# New Line Added in file write when inserting text

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've tried several ways to append a string to a line being written to a file when reading from another file (as well as in place using fileinput). I'm definitely missing something but trying different approaches for a few hours has not fixed the problem.

The latest approach is below, which still results in the imagelist being on a new line after the datarow where the goal is to output them to a single line.

```
for datarow in oldfile:        
    rowcols     = datarow.split('|')    
    imagelist   = []
    image_seed  = rowcols[headers.index('Group ID')]+'_'+rowcols[headers.index('Case ID')]+'_'+rowcols[headers.index('Contact ID')]

    if isfirstrow:
        newfile.write(headerrow)
        isfirstrow = False
    else:
        for imagename in imagefiles:
            if image_seed in imagename:
                imagelist.append(os.path.basename(imagename))
        if len(imagelist) > 0:
            imagelist.insert(0, datarow)
            newfile.write('|'.join(imagelist)+'\n')
        else: newfile.write(datarow)
```

Thanks in advance for you input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some reminent `'\n'` either in front of your 1st item of your `imagelist` or after `datarow`. Unfortunately you dont show how you read `oldfile`.

Soluttion, clean `'\n'` from it:

```
imagelist.insert(0, datarow.rstrip('\n'))                      # rstrip for clean on end
newfile.write('|'.join(x.strip('\n') for x in imagelist)+'\n') # strip: clean both ends
```

Maybe you should give this a read:    [How to debug small programs (#5)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

You might also need to clean up

```
 else: newfile.write(datarow.rstrip('\n')+'\n')          # make it consistently have a \n
```

Comment: Thanks, imagelist.insert(0, datarow.rstrip('\n'))  did the trick.